# How to create an custom entry/exit signal in VectorBT?

Tags: vector, algorithmic-trading, trading, back-testing

thanks for reading!
I'm trying to backtest a strategy that I wrote in Pinescrpt, and I struggle to create my entry conditions.

So this is the code

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import vectorbt as vbt
from datetime import datetime
from binance.client import Client
symbols=['SOLUSDT', 'BNBUSDT']
price = 

vbt.BinanceData.download(symbols, 
start= '5 days ago UTC', 
end= 'Now UTC', 
interval='30m', missing_index='drop'
).get(['High', 'Low', 'Open', 'Close'])
high = price[0]
low = price[1]
open = price[2]
close = price[3]
stoch = vbt.STOCH.run(
high=high, 
low=low, 
close = close, 
k_window = 14 
)
```

And I want to add

```
entries = abs(stoch.percent_k['SOLUSDT'] -
 stoch.percent_k['SOLUSDT']) > 50 # (mi intention with abs is to get the absolute value)

    exits = abs(stoch.percent_k['SOLUSDT'] - 
 stoch.percent_k['SOLUSDT']) < 5
    portfolio = vbt.Portfolio.from_signals(price[3], entries, exits, init_cash=10000)
```

I pretend to trigger a short order in a symbol and a long order in the second simultaneously with those signals.

And if anyone has a recommendation about where to find educational resources about this particular package (besides the official web) is welcome. I have read the examples in the doc, but it still fills a bit too complex for my level.

Comment: could you post some code as to how you resolved this? It would help me out. thx.

Comment: I didn't solve it yet, is on my "to-do" list.